# Adding meta values for each id where post_type = ?? wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I just added a custom field to a specific `post_type`. Lets say the post type is "Book".

I want to insert into the database default value of 0 for every `post_id` with `post_type` Book.

Basically I need to take the `post_id`, using that `post_id` add `post_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value` to the postmeta table.

some psuedo insert statement might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO postmeta WHERE (post_type = "Book" FROM other_table GET post_id) post_id = post_id, meta_key = newfield, meta_value = 0
```

Another solution might be to change how I am querying posts in wordpress:

Currently only posts that have the specific meta_key filled out are being pulled when I query using the meta_key parameter. Is there a way to show posts that also do not have this meta_key? I need it for sorting the posts that do have the meta_key.

Edit:

I tried this in the wp database:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES((SELECT ID FROM wp_posts tb WHERE tb.post_type = 'support'),'category_order','0')
```

This is basically what I want to do except it should allow for multiple values. It currently does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do a job like this in the past and I stick to the Wordpress Foundations. I would run away from SQL while adding data to posts.

Basically I did a page template and inside I would just loop the posts and use update_post_meta, like this:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'book',
);

query_posts( $args );

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//update the post meta, while looping
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fieldname', 0);

endwhile;

?>
```

Just tested the code and it's working.

Comment: cool solution. i ended up just using a custom query and it also worked. i agree though, when dealing with wordpress it is best to not manually manipulate the database.

Comment: so would you just save this in `functions` - then upload to server, double check that it worked, and then delete the code from `functions` so it doesnt over write modified `fieldname` values?

Comment: or should you add it as an action on `init` ?

Comment: Hi @RobBenz. No, You create a new page template, assign it to a page in the admin area and every time you open that page it will trigger the update_post_meta event.